# In Kotlin, why is (-1 ushr 4) different from -1.ushr(4)?

Tags: kotlin, bitwise-operators, infix-operator

In both Kotlin REPL and Kotlin/JVM:

- `-1 ushr 4` evaluates to `268435455`
- `-1.ushr(4)` evaluates to `0`

The first one is correct, as -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF, so 0x0FFFFFFF is 268435455, but what makes the second different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on operator priority. In the first case, the operation is resolved as `(-1) ushr 4`, while in the second case it's `-(1 ushr 4)`.

This happens because (quoting the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation)):

> Infix function calls have lower precedence than the arithmetic operators, type casts, and the rangeTo operator. The following expressions are equivalent:
>
> `1 shl 2 + 3` and `1 shl (2 + 3)`

While method call has a higher priority than `-`.